# Rotate CIImage in Swift 2 using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation

Tags: rotation, ciimage

I try and rotate a CIImage in Swift2 using

```
let rotatedImage        = someCIImage.imageByApplyingTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI / 2.0))))
```

When I look at the sized of the resulting rectangle, it has been rotated. (it was 1000x500 and now is 500x1000). However, the calculations I do subsequently (convert to bitmap and access individual pixels) indicate differently. Am I right that the the above transformation rotates around the center of the image, i.e. in the above example around 500/250?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That transform rotates around the image's origin. This version sets the pivot point to the centre:

```
var tx = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(
    image.extent.width / 2,
    image.extent.height / 2)

tx = CGAffineTransformRotate(
    tx,
    CGFloat(M_PI_2))

tx = CGAffineTransformTranslate(
    tx,
    -image.extent.width / 2,
    -image.extent.height / 2)

var transformImage = CIFilter(
    name: "CIAffineTransform",
    withInputParameters: [
        kCIInputImageKey: image,
        kCIInputTransformKey: NSValue(CGAffineTransform: tx)])!.outputImage!
```

Simon

Comment: You could use `midX` and `midY` instead of `width / 2` and `height / 2`

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 5, the code gets nicer. This is a `CIImage` extension method to easily rotate itself around the center.

```
func rotate(_ angle: CGFloat) -> CIImage {
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: extent.midX, y: extent.midY)
        .rotated(by: angle)
        .translatedBy(x: -extent.midX, y: -extent.midY)
    return applyingFilter("CIAffineTransform", parameters: [kCIInputTransformKey: transform])
}
```